# How to check null condition in react Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Like normally we write

```
if(num1==""){
do nothing
}else{
do something}
```

how do we write it in react native syntax, below is my code

I already tried a lot but failed to get the point why is it giving an error

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    num1 : "",
     num2 : "",
     result: ""
  }

  addBtnPressed = () => {
    this.setState({
      if({num1 == "" || num2 == ""}){
        alert('Field Empty')
      }else{
        result: eval(this.state.num1 +"+"+ this.state.num2)
      }
     });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
          keyboardType={"numeric"}
          placeholder="Enter 1st Number" 
          onChangeText={num1 => this.setState({num1})}/>

        <TextInput 
          keyboardType={"numeric"}
          placeholder="Enter 2nd Number" 
          onChangeText={num2 => this.setState({num2})}/>
        <Button title="ADD" onPress={this.addBtnPressed}/>
         <Text>{this.state.result}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `if-else` condition in `setState`.

Also don't use `eval`. From [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/javascript-eval),

> It is not recommended to use eval() because it is slow, not secure, and makes code unreadable and maintainable.

Instead you can use `parseInt`.

```
addBtnPressed = () => {
    const {num1,num2} = this.state;
    if(num1 === "" || num2 === ""){
        alert('Field Empty')
    }else{
        this.setState({ result: parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2) }, ()=>console.log(this.state.result))
    }
}
```

Another way is (Avoidable),

```
addBtnPressed = () => {
    this.setState( prevState => {
      if(prevState.num1 === "" || prevState.num2 === ""){
        alert('Field Empty')
      }
      return { result: parseInt(prevState.num1) + parseInt(prevState.num2) }
    }, () => console.log(this.state.result));
}
```

Read more about [setState](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an `if` statement inside  `setState`

```
addBtnPressed = () => {
    const { num1, num2 } = this.state
    if(num1 == "" || num2 == "") 
        return alert('Field Empty')  
    this.setState({result: eval(this.state.num1 +"+"+ this.state.num2)})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is calling the `setState` func with if-else  upon call of `addBtnPressed` func and you arent accessing the state variables with the syntax `this.state.num1` rather you've used num1 which is causing the error. Since your question is unclear, but from your code i figured out like you need to check if user has entered num1 and num2 otherwise give alert. so you can do this on `addBtnPressed` :

`if(this.state.num1 && this.state.num2){
       this.setState({ result: parseInt(this.state.num1) + parseInt(this.state.num2) });
       }else{
    alert('Field Empty');
    }`

The above code is short and sweet and would do your work. And a reminder , never use if and else within setState as mentioned by dupocas and ravibugal above.